# ACE editor displaying a line

Tags: ace-editor

While using ACE editor I've observed that a mysterious line is being displayed at the center of the editor. How do i fix this?

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That line is called as Print Margin, include

```
editor.setShowPrintMargin(false);
```

in your code.

Answer (score 4):

It is not a mysterious line but a print margin - simple line at the specified column, to help seeing when lines become too long.

To disable it we can also use,

```
editor.setOption("showPrintMargin", false)
```